# Add text to image with FreeImage

Tags: c++, c, freeimage

How I can add some texts into a image using FreeImage ( http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/ ) ?

I searched the documentation and found no information on how I can do this

Comment: Could you add a link to the FreeImage libraries you intend to use?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Perhaps the similarly named [FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/) would be useful to you?

Answer (score 2):

Rendering text to image is not doable with FreeImage, as is noted on their own forum, albeit quite a long ago, but from their docs this does not seem to have changed:

https://sourceforge.net/p/freeimage/discussion/36110/thread/6c519d97/

If rendering text to image is what you need, there are other open source alternatives that do this, including ImageMagick, as noted in the forum post.